# Why does a type literal behave differently than a type parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Consider this type ([see in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIHUHsCcGsDOxgBcCeAHApuAcgK4A2RAlogBYDS26iAkgHYA8A8gDTgBq4AvOI2JFwAH3AFGAE2wAzUo2ySAfH3ABvYOHABtKuHnh4taDPCsAugC4BQ0eKmz5i8NgAeqbFMRnd5zVvAAfnAqfy1rBQA3bFhgAF9tI3QTMz9QCAARaGxERkBMAlRwAHc4eFAAKjQsXEIScmpaBhYOblVBEjsJaTkFZVUNLV19RkNjUwtrHjcPLx8qPwCgkLDwCOxo2ISklItgcpAUMHAAWlPTlHkPWBkAQwBjXAAVHNQAJRvGAHNcAftup0k1i6jl67H87TIlAitjEwJ6ijBcUOEAAAqhEMc3Dg7qhMbBYHBgERsIVMATMABGay1SENOhMZjPRBvD7fFT8ADkcIBHPAN28d2gjGZRJJ4DJ0EwACZqUJ6jR6SwmSyvth2eAORD6rz%20eBBcLUCh0uAZBIcaQheAALYEVA3DysABGACtGUoABTQF3WR6cCWYWV1SgKppuziRG5EAjYAAKBMipGksAAlEA)) which extracts all properties from the type `O` (think, *object*) to which null and undefined are both assignable. Note that the type parameter `V` is unused and instead `null | undefined` appears verbatim in the type definition.

```js
type NullishKeysIn<O, V = null | undefined> = {
  [K in keyof O]: null | undefined extends O[K]
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof O]
```

This type works as intended and extracts only `nullish` from this interface:

```js
interface TestRange {
  undefined: undefined,
  nullish: null | undefined,
}

// @ts-expect-error – Type '"undefined"' is not assignable to type '"nullish"'
let prop1: NullishKeysIn<TestRange> = 'undefined' as const
let prop2: NullishKeysIn<TestRange> = 'nullish' as const
```

However, when I replace the verbatim type `null | undefined` in the definition of `NullishKeys` with the type parameter `V`, which defaults to the same type, `NullishKeys` also extracts the key `undefined` from the test range:

```js
type NullishKeysIn<O, V = null | undefined> = {
  [K in keyof O]: V extends O[K]
    ? K
    : never
}[keyof O]

interface TestRange {
  undefined: undefined,
  nullish: null | undefined,
}

// no error
let prop1: NullishKeysIn<TestRange> = 'undefined' as const
let prop2: NullishKeysIn<TestRange> = 'nullish' as const
```

Why does TypeScript behave differently in this case? Is it possible to make `NullishKeysIn` work with a type parameter that is a union of types?

Comment: Conditional types that check naked type parameters are distributive over unions. The easiest way to prevent that is to change `T extends U ? V : W` to `[T] extends [U] ? V : W`. See linked q/a for more info.